# How do I get to create a notification when user presses a certain button?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I know how to display a notification, but when I put it on "onOptionsItemSelected" menu, it doesn't create the notification. I'm most likely missing something, I just don't know what that is. heres the code:

```
@TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void notification() {
    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNote);

    String Title = etTitle.toString();
    String Note = etNote.toString();

    //boolean success = true;


    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setContentTitle(Title)
            .setContentText(Note)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);


    //vibrates when notification comes up
    Notification note = notification.build();
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    note.extras.getBoolean(Notification.EXTRA_SHOW_WHEN);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();


    resultIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "hi");
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, notification.build());


}
```

^thats my method to create the notification

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:      
            actionSave();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_delete:
            actionDelete();
            return true;
        case R.id.Alarm:

            return true;
        case R.id.Pin:
            notification();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

^and that's my onOptionsItemSelected menu, R.id.Pin is the button to create the notification.

Any suggestions would be great help. Thank you.
Note:I'm only entry level programmer for java, so I may not know all the code I was suppose to learn.

Comment: (offtopic) do you know about `break`?

Comment: @eduyayo I haven't learned it yet honestly

Comment: @eduyayo May I ask why?

Comment: Most of the people you'll bump on will ask you to follow kind of a *code standard*. And some of them may add a comment asking you to make your code *readable* before even getting into it.